# replacement of nditer for numpy array for pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I am looking for similar functionality for pytorch tensor as of nditer of numpy array, see this link with a small example. 
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/replacement-of-np-nditer-for-torch/64024?u=songqsh

Comment: `nditer` is almost always a bad way to interact with NumPy arrays, and that will often be even more true for PyTorch tensors. Your averaging function can be written more efficiently without `nditer`.

Comment: Using `nditer` with NumPy is like dragging your car behind you by hand. You're not taking advantage of the power of NumPy, or the car.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Would you please write a simple and efficient code without nditer? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @kenneth you need to submit different question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comments that iterating element by element is reraly a good idea for interaction with arrays or tensors. `nditer` has lots of functionality, here is just an iteration through all elements in the tensor which returns coordinates of the element together with element itself:

```
def deep_iter(data, ix=tuple()):
    try:
        for i, element in enumerate(data):
            yield from deep_iter(element, ix + (i,))
    except:
        yield ix, data
```

So for example at pytorch forum it can be used as following:

```
new_values = {}
for i, value in deep_iter(a):
    if all(map(lambda x: 0 < x < (a.shape[1] - 1), i)):
        new_values[i] = calc_average(i, a) #write func to calc average

for i, new_value in new_values.items():
    a[i] = new_value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this neatly done code. Although I am not expert in programming, I can tell this is very advanced. I will revise this and try to post the full script to pytorch forum.

Comment: I've just posted the entire code here, https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/replacement-of-np-nditer-for-torch/64024?u=songqsh

Comment: Good job, mate. You should have deleted '#write func to calc average' comment :D